# Update a table from list or np.array using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, numpy

Is it possible to update an existing table with an array or a list if the number and order of columns and rows is identical?

I created an array without column headers. For example:

```
array = 

[[-0.17142857  2.92857143  2.76190476  0.22857143 -0.0952381 ]
 [ 0.10434783  1.86335404 -0.39130435  6.          0.7826087 ]
 [-0.053125    4.8875      0.2125      3.          0.56666667]
 [ 0.0730897   2.55813953  0.          4.94573643  0.30697674]
 [ 0.36        3.24        0.24        2.          0.63      ]]
```

or the same as a list:

```
list = []

[[-0.17142857142857143, 2.9285714285714284, 2.761904761904762, 0.2285714285714286, -0.09523809523809523], 
 [0.10434782608695653, 1.8633540372670807, -0.3913043478260869, 6.0, 0.7826086956521738], 
 [-0.053125, 4.8875, 0.2125, 3.0, 0.5666666666666667], 
 [0.07308970099667773, 2.558139534883721, 0.0, 4.945736434108527, 0.3069767441860465], 
 [0.36, 3.24, 0.24, 2.0, 0.63]]
```

Now I want to use this to update my table, such as:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, (fieldNameList)) as cursor: 

    for row in cursor:
        for i in range(len(fieldNameList)):

    >>>           row[i] = array or list ?             <<< ???

    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

`fieldNameList` generated using `arcpy.ListFields`

```
fieldNameList = [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']
```

The number of columns and number of rows of the list (array) are identical to those of the field list. Also, the order of columns and rows is identical.

Comment: You can do it using the updateRow(row) method where row is a list or tuple in the same order as your field list.  So it would be row = list or tuple outside a for loop.  That method says that row is "A list or tuple of values. The order of values should be in the same order as the fields.

When updating fields, if the incoming values match the type of field, the values will be cast as necessary. For example, a value of 1.0 to a string field will be added as "1.0", and a value of "25" added to a float field will be added as 25.0."  Insert cursors use the insertRow(row) method the same way.

Comment: It would not involve the two for loops you showed, since you don't access each field in the row with the i counter from the range.  You would only use the top for loop: "for row in cursor:".  Inside that loop you would just use:  "row = listofvalues" or "row = tupleofvalues".  I suppose "row = List(npArray) would work too.

Comment: can you an example? I understand but do not know how to implement it .. I am an absolute beginner in using Python

Comment: StopIteration: iteration not started...  for row in cursor:
  
                
   row = list

    cursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: Why don't you just use [NumPyArrayToTable](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000016000000) to replace the table instead of updating every row and column in it?

Comment: Because I do not have a column headers. also, I have no indexed columns to join ..

Comment: Adding column headers looks like it is covered in that help i.e. convert it to a structured array. I'm unclear why you need "indexed columns to join" when if you need them you can index the columns after creating the table.

Comment: PolyGeo - replacing a table is often not desirable.  He may actually only intend to update 5 rows out of 100.  If he intends to replace the entire table then you are correct.  However, in general if I make the choice to use an updateCursor as opposed to a geoprocessing tool or insertCursor I already have decided that I do not want to replace the table.

Comment: kamfuebu - if you have not index column (ObjectID or otherwise) and have no field names, then what is the data source.  If it is not a table (i.e., a spreadsheet) you cannot use an update cursor at all until you convert it to a table.  Also how can your target table have no field names?  It cannot be a table if that is true.

Comment: Richard - I created the array using the search cursor... array = []

 
       
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_1,(fieldNameList_1)) as sCur: 
 
 
 for row in sCur:
  
  
   
   iteracija_kolona_1 = [row[i] for i in range(len(fieldNameList_1))]
   array.append(iteracija_kolona_1) 
   

 matrica_1 = np.array(array)

Comment: I have two matrices ... supposed to conduct complicated calculations ... I have to use numpy ... everything works ... the problem is when the array I want to go back to the table ... and how it all to index

Comment: I am an absolute beginner in using python ... maybe I have the wrong approach but do not know better

Comment: What relationship do the matrices have to the table you are writing to?  Does the table you are writing to contain any data?  Did the matrix calculations derive from records in the table and need to be written back?  If so you have to revise the matrix calculations to also track the ObjectID of the table the values came from to return it to that record.  If the matrices have no relationship to any pre-existing feature or table record then you have no need for an update cursor.  In that case you must use an insert cursor to create new records or NumPyArrayToTable to create a new table.

Answer (score 4):

Actually now that I have read your list more closely you cannot and should not use the list you have shown using an update cursor.  You can only use one list of values at a time to update just one row.  There is no way to update many rows with a single list or tuple in one operation using an updateCursor.  But you can iterate the list with the row loop as shown below:

```
import arcpy

myList = [[-0.17142857, 2.92857143, 2.76190476, 0.22857143, -0.0952381 ], [ 0.10434783, 1.86335404, -0.39130435, 6, 0.7826087 ], [-0.053125, 4.8875, 0.2125, 3, 0.56666667], [ 0.0730897, 2.55813953, 0, 4.94573643, 0.30697674], [ 0.36, 3.24, 0.24, 2, 0.63]]

fc = "myFC"

fieldNameList = [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']

i = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, (fieldNameList)) as cursor: 
  for row in cursor:
    i += 1
    row = myList[i]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

However, there are many failure possibilities with the code above.  It writes to the wrong record if the rows are read in any order that is different from the list order.  An error will also occur if more than 5 rows are read by the cursor.  Generally creating lists that attempt to predict the number and order of rows returned by the cursor is far too much trouble and a waste of time.

A better approach is to use a dictionary to look up a unique value or set of values in each row returned by the cursor and only update rows that match.  Dictionaries are better than lists and tuples for random order matching, so you don't worry about the row order, only the field order.

So this is better:

```
import arcpy

myDict = {1:[-0.17142857, 2.92857143, 2.76190476, 0.22857143, -0.0952381 ],  2:[ 0.10434783, 1.86335404, -0.39130435, 6, 0.7826087 ], 4:[-0.053125, 4.8875, 0.2125, 3, 0.56666667], 8:[ 0.0730897, 2.55813953, 0, 4.94573643, 0.30697674], 10:[ 0.36, 3.24, 0.24, 2, 0.63]}

fc = "myFC"

fieldNameList = ["OID@", u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, (fieldNameList)) as cursor: 
  for row in cursor:
    if row[0] in myDict:
      for n in range(1,len(fieldNameList)):
        row[n] = myDict[row[0]][n-1]
      cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The code with the dictionary will only update a maximum of 5 rows and only those rows with an ObjectID value of 1, 2, 4, 8 or 10.  It may update fewer than 5 rows if the rows returned by the cursor do not include all 5 of the ObjectIDs in my dictionary.  It won't update any row that does not have an ObjectID  of 1, 2, 4, 8 or 10.  This code will not fail if the cursor returns more or less rows than the five listed in the dictionary.  It is efficient, since unlike a list or tuple I do not have to loop through the dictionary keys to match the ObjectID of the current row being read and I do not have to predict the order of the rows returned by the cursor in advance.  As a result the dictionary below will have the same result as the dictionary above:

```
myDict = {2:[ 0.10434783, 1.86335404, -0.39130435, 6, 0.7826087], 4:[-0.053125, 4.8875, 0.2125, 3,  0.56666667], 1:[-0.17142857, 2.92857143, 2.76190476, 0.22857143, -0.0952381 ], 8:[ 0.0730897, 2.55813953, 0, 4.94573643, 0.30697674], 10:[ 0.36, 3.24, 0.24, 2, 0.63]}
```

See my blog on [Turbo Charging Data Manipulation using Python Cursors and Dictionaries](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries) for more on how to use dictionaries for random record matching between a data source converted to a dictionary and a target cursor as well.

If you have no index to match then it is best to not use an update cursor at all and just replace the source table, since an update cursor normally assumes you want to update existing records, which is not usually done to just any random record.  If you want to just trash all existing records and replace them with new records then a complete table replacement is best.  If you do not want to update existing records and just want to insert the 5 new records, then use an insert cursor, not an update cursor.